# Как объединить и обработать диапазон по признаку

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня в [гугл таблице](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zksKbJCiZKYTYjhtftb83eIURYcCPnX_lrHlCfYH8Mw/edit?usp=sharing) есть группы строк, данные которых надо обрабатывать по группами:

1. Группы формируются по "Признак2"
2. Результат выводится в строках по "Признак1"="Группа"

**Вопрос:** как получить диапазоны в колонках, отфильтрованные по признаку из колонки B, для последующей обработки:

В общем тут 2 задачи, так как я подозреваю что их можно решить получив диапазон группы.

**Задача 1:** Объединить/сцепить ячейки из колонки "C" погруппно в текст. (пример колонка "E").

Пробовал через FILTER, но не робит

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ЕСЛИ(A2:A="Группа";FILTER(C:C;B2:B=(ЕСЛИ(A2:A="Группа";B2:B;""));"")))
```

А для TEXTJOIN нужен диапазон

**Задача 2:** Получить min-max значения групп из колонки "D", (пример колонка "F").

У меня получилось, но она не работает через ARRAYFORMULA

```
=ЕСЛИ(A:A="Группа";"min "&(MINIFS(D:D;B:B;B3)&",max "&MAXIFS(D:D;B:B;B3));"")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пример таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zksKbJCiZKYTYjhtftb83eIURYcCPnX_lrHlCfYH8Mw/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

Решение, хоть и очевидно, требует вникнуть в суть происходящего.

Идея в том, чтобы собрать группы заголовков через `QUERY`, обработать пробелы и завершить вывод через `VLOOKUP` только для нужных строк.

```
=INDEX(IF(A3:A="Группа";
  VLOOKUP(
    B3:B;
    {
      UNIQUE(B3:B)\
     TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(B3:B=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B3:B));C3:C&", ";"");;9^9));"(^\s+|\s*,\s*$)";""))
    };
    2;
 );
))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теже яйца, вид сбоку

```
=INDEX(IF(A3:A="Группа";
  "min: " & VLOOKUP(
    B3:B;
   QUERY(A3:D;"select B, min(D), max(D) where A='' group by B label B'' ";1);
    2;
 ) & ", max: " & VLOOKUP(
    B3:B;
   QUERY(A3:D;"select B, min(D), max(D) where A='' group by B label B'' ";1);
    3;
 );))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо, что привели ссылки на мой сайт в примере. Теперь я понимаю, что нужно еще добавить информации относительно того, как принимать решения по расчету в таких ситуациях.

Comment: В колонке для объединения есть пустые ячейки, в результате добавляются запятые: "a1, a2, , , , , ," как игнорировать пустые ячейки?

Comment: @ЛеонидБрус, надо делать качественные заготовки.

Comment: @ contributorpw Вот изменил вашу формулу, чтоб игнорировала пустые ячейки, и не реагировала на пробелы в данных: `=ИНДЕКС(ЕСЛИ(A3:A="Группа";
  ВПР(
    B3:B;
    {
      UNIQUE(B3:B)\
     REGEXREPLACE( REGEXREPLACE(СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(REGEXREPLACE(ТРАНСП(QUERY(ЕСЛИ(B3:B=ТРАНСП(UNIQUE(B3:B));REGEXREPLACE(C3:C;" ";"❤")&" ";"");;9^9));" ";" "));" ";",");"❤";" ")
    };
    2;
 );
)) `

Comment: @ЛеонидБрус, можете отметить вопрос как решение, если вам подошло.